# How to fetch distinct values from multiple rows of select query?

Tags: sql, database

I have used query as

```
string getPlayers = " Select Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5 from tbl_game where Player1=" + userid + " OR Player2=" + userid + " OR Player3=" + userid + " OR Player4=" + userid + " OR Player5=" + userid + " AND Complete = 'No' ";
```

It gives result as multiple rows that fulfills the condition.

But I want to store values of distinct `Player1,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5` in variables  returned from select query, so that i can use these values for further case.

How can i do this ?

Please help me. I am very confused.

EDITED :

I got the result of select query as -

```
(1,2,2,4,5)
(2,3,1,4,5)
(4,3,5,1,2)
```

Where 1,2,3,4,5 are userids(players).

I want store these userids in variables as -

```
p1=1 , p2=2 , p3=3 ,p4=4, p5=5
```

Comment: "I am very confused." After reading your question, I became confused too. Can you explain what you need with an example?

Comment: @MarkByers - i have edited my question and explained what i want

Comment: @RKP - Your short term intention is now clear but your long term intention is not.  SQL is not very friendly to procedural kind of processing (it is tedious to develop and it executes slowly).  If that subsequent processing is intended to happen in SQL, please reconsider.  If you have a non-database programming language in mind, please retag (edit and enter additional tags).

Answer (score 0):

```
string getPlayer1 = (" select var1 from (" Select distinct Player1 as var1 ,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5 from tbl_game where Player1=" + userid + " OR Player2=" + userid + " OR Player3=" + userid + " OR Player4=" + userid + " OR Player5=" + userid + " AND Complete = 'No' "));
```

var1 will have a value of player1. Repeat this for all other players. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: thanks for reply. but it gives an error '"Every derived table must have its own alias"'

Comment: string getPlayer1 = (" select var1 from (" Select distinct Player1 as var1 ,Player2,Player3,Player4,Player5 from tbl_game where Player1=" + userid + " OR Player2=" + userid + " OR Player3=" + userid + " OR Player4=" + userid + " OR Player5=" + userid + " AND Complete = 'No' ") as tab1);
Try this and let me know